# Warehouse and SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I develop some application that has database wery generic so really can't use it for reporting. So I need solution how to create reporting. I'm developer so my knowledge in DBA domain is bounded. For now I have ideo to create another database where I'll pu denormalized data from original db. So I saw that I could use SSIS for that and woul be glad if someone could give me some advice how to attack that problem. Should I sync data once a day and run reports that way. Is there solution to sync data allways so reports would be up to date? Please any advice.. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered simply creating a set of reporting views on top of your existing database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damir,

What I get from your message is that you are getting close to build a Datawarehouse using a Star Schema pattern.

You could have two databases, One with normalized data and the other one with the Star Schema pattern (Your DW), and then create a script that would use your normalized data and put them in your datawarehouse. For the frequency of your script it is up to you : After each transaction, every hour, once a day, etc...

The advantage of having a datawarehouse is that you will be able to use OLAP cubes and the MDX language for your reports. It's a plus !

Hope it could help,

Comment: Can you please tell me does script truncate all data each time and putt new. And how is that affected to performance?

Comment: @Damir : Look on internet at the difference between 'Bulk loading' and 'Incremental loading'. You'll find plenty definition. Then the script behave upon your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on sql server 2005 or greater, explore Merge statement.
For smaller tables, just truncate and reload. 'Smaller' could be subjective - but if takes less than 2-3 minutes to load, that could be termed as small. Obviously, during that period any query that uses such tables would fail.